# Browser cache problems when accessing PHP files with Mootools' SqueezeBox

Tags: php, caching, mootools

I am using Squeeze Box to access a PHP file which prints an alert for the user based on the link clicked (i.e. PHP file uses $_GET variable).

The problem is when I click once the alert box open correctly but when I click the link again, the result appears twice i.e. it duplicates itself and the results continue replicating each time the link is clicked.

But when I close the browser, the problem restarts again, is there a solution for this problem. (And the problem appears in both Mozilla and IE)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not familiar with squeezebox but there are normally a few tactics for this.

- switch to `$_POST` not `$_GET`
- append a random querystring to each
  request - e.g. a timestamp
- add no-cache headers to PHP file.

no-cache would look something like this:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```